# Extjs 5, DD ordering stops working after clear sorting

Tags: extjs

I have grid panel with DragAndDrop for reordering rows.

after the grid is loaded I do able to reorder rows with DD,
but if I call sort() on store of the grid I cannot reordering rows with DD anymore,
even if I call sorters.clear()

What I should do to be able reordering rows with DD after sorting is applied

Comment: Any chance you can show a basic use case on fiddle.sencha.com ?

Comment: here you go https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ge7

Comment: Having looked through the source code this looks like it is not possible at the moment without some untrivial changes to the source and the various components of DragDrop.  For now I would suggest you could just reinitiate the grid and store from scratch.